# How to prevent data stored using LsaStorePrivateData to be easily read from anyone from remote machine using LsaRetrievePrivateData?

Tags: windows, security, registrykey

I store some data on computer A with LsaStorePrivateData. The problem is that it is easily readable using LsaRetrievePrivateData api func from any other PC on the same local network. How can I prevent this? Stopping 'remote registry' service does not help. Any other trick to prevent remote access to data stored with LsaStorePrivateData?

Regards,
Artur

Comment: The data can only be retrieved by someone who is already an admin on computer A.  Why is this a problem?

Comment: The problem is that it ('protected' data) can be read from remote computer by literally anyone. I've checked that. Being logged on as user X on one computer I can read data ('protected' with LsaStorePrivateData) stored by user Z on a different machine that is why I try to figure out what should be set/turned off on machine with stored data to prevent reading that data from remote hosts.

Comment: So user X is a domain admin or local admin on the machine where the files are stored?  Anyway, the CryptProtectData function lets you store data so that only a single user can decrypt it.

Comment: OK - I've found the answer by myself. Once I use a key name with "L$" prefix I create so called Local Private Data Object. Quote from (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722416) "Local private data objects can only be read locally from the computer storing the object. Attempting to read them remotely results in a STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED error. Local private data objects have key names that begin with the prefix "L$"." So without that prefix everyone can (knowing the key) read your 'private' data even remotely. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Anyone who could retrieve the data before will still be able to retrieve it now, if they really want to.  All they'd need to do is launch a process on your machine to call LsaRetrievePrivateData on their behalf.  You can't protect yourself from anyone with administrator credentials!

Comment: If this is really working for someone without admin credentials on the target system, either there's a major security bug in Windows, or there's something seriously wrong with the machine you're using.

Comment: Reading my encoded stuff by admins is OK with me (btw - as far as I know they would have to know the key for stored data first). After all admins to my PCs are trusted comparing to anyone in the network being able to read my data freely remotely.

Comment: @Harry: I forgot one thing - being able to remotely read data (stored with LsaStorePrivateData) - for which the key does not have a prefix - seems to be normal behavior for Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says "Private data objects which do not use any of the preceding key name conventions can be accessed remotely". So this behavior is intentional and cannot be considered a bug. Thanks for all comments anyway.

Comment: The documentation for LsaStorePrivateData says "the key has a DACL that allows only the creator and administrators to read the data".  This restriction should be enforced regardless of whether the access is local or remote, and if it isn't, that's a bug.

Comment: let's not argue - anyway when I use no L$ prefix for the key I managed to read my data remotely as a regular pc user  -thanks Harry

Comment: I've written some test code but I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.  Would you mind emailing me a copy of your test code so that I can see if you are doing something differently?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do anything, unless:

- the operating system on the target machine is badly corrupted, in which case a reinstallation is probably the only safe approach.
- you have stored the data using a guest account, or some other account which untrusted users have access to, in which case the answer is to not do that. :-)

The documentation for LsaStorePrivateData says:

> The data stored by the LsaStorePrivateData function is not absolutey protected. However, the data is encrypted before being stored, and the key has a DACL that allows only the creator and administrators to read the data.

This test code may be useful for anyone interested in the subject, or wanting to double-check that their machine is secure in this respect.  My own tests using this code confirmed the documented behaviour.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ntsecapi.h>

#include <stdio.h>

wchar_t keyname_string[] = L"harrytest";

LSA_UNICODE_STRING keyname;

LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES lsa_object_attributes;

int set(void)
{
    LSA_HANDLE ph;
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING secretdata;
    wchar_t secretdata_buffer[2];

    DWORD status;

    status = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &lsa_object_attributes, POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, &ph);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaOpenPolicy: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    secretdata.Length = 2;
    secretdata.MaximumLength = sizeof(secretdata_buffer);
    secretdata.Buffer = secretdata_buffer;
    secretdata_buffer[0] = L'x';
    secretdata_buffer[1] = L'\0';

    status = LsaStorePrivateData(ph, &keyname, &secretdata);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaStorePrivateData: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}

int get(wchar_t * target_string)
{
    LSA_HANDLE ph;
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING * secretdata;
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING target;

    DWORD status;

    if (target_string != NULL)
    {
        target.Length = wcslen(target_string) * 2;
        target.MaximumLength = target.Length + 2;
        target.Buffer = target_string;
    }

    status = LsaOpenPolicy(target_string ? &target : NULL, &lsa_object_attributes, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &ph);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaOpenPolicy: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    status = LsaRetrievePrivateData(ph, &keyname, &secretdata);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaRetrievePrivateData: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    if (secretdata == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL pointer retrieved\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%u bytes retrieved\n", secretdata->Length);
    return 0;
}

int delete_data(void)
{
    LSA_HANDLE ph;

    DWORD status;

    status = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &lsa_object_attributes, POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, &ph);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaOpenPolicy: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    status = LsaStorePrivateData(ph, &keyname, NULL);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("LsaStorePrivateData: %X\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
    keyname.Length = wcslen(keyname_string) * 2;
    keyname.MaximumLength = keyname.Length + 2;
    keyname.Buffer = keyname_string;

    lsa_object_attributes.Length = sizeof(lsa_object_attributes);
    lsa_object_attributes.RootDirectory = NULL;
    lsa_object_attributes.ObjectName = NULL;
    lsa_object_attributes.Attributes = 0;
    lsa_object_attributes.SecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    lsa_object_attributes.SecurityQualityOfService = NULL;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"set") == 0)
        {
            return set();
        }
        if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"delete") == 0)
        {
            return delete_data();
        }
        else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"get") == 0)
        {
            if (argc == 2)
            {
                return get(NULL);
            }
            else if (argc == 3)
            {
                return get(argv[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Syntax:\n"
         "testprivatedata set\n"
         "testprivatedata get\n"
         "testprivatedata get \\\\target\n"
         "testprivatedata delete\n");
    return 1;
}
```